# Why spoj is giving Wrong Answer for this solution of "Even Count"

Tags: c, algorithm

I am trying to solve [GEEK COUNT](http://www.spoj.com/SPOJ/problems/GEEKOUNT/) problem on spoj. My approach for this problem is finding the numbers with all odd digits first and then subtract it from the given number. For finding number count with all odd digit, I am using simple permutation. 
It is giving me correct answer for all the possible test-cases. I have tried to cross check it against brute-force approach also but still unable to find the test case with wrong solution.

```
#include<stdio.h>
unsigned long long int myPow(unsigned long long int N, unsigned long long int k)
{
    unsigned long long int result;
    if(k==0)
        return 1;
    if(k==1)
        return N;
    result=myPow(N,k>>1);
    if(k%2==1)
        return result*result*N;
    return result*result;

}
unsigned long long int solveForLessThan(unsigned long long int N)
{
    unsigned long long int result,temp_N;
    int power=0,digits[20],flag=0;
    temp_N=N;
    result=0;
    while(temp_N/10!=0)
    {
        result+=myPow(5,power+1);
        digits[power]=temp_N%10;
        power++;
        temp_N=temp_N/10;
    }
    digits[power]=temp_N;
    while(power>0)
    {
        if(digits[power]%2==0)
        {
            result+=(digits[power]/2)*myPow(5,power);
            flag=1;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            flag=0;
            result+=(digits[power]/2)*myPow(5,power);
        }
        power--;
    }
    if(!flag)
    {
        result+=((digits[power]+1)/2);
    }
    return N-result;
}

int main()
{
    int test_cases;
    unsigned long long int L,R;


    for(scanf("%d",&test_cases);test_cases>=0;test_cases--)
    {
        scanf("%llu",&L);
        scanf("%llu",&R);
        printf("%llu\n",(solveForLessThan(R)-solveForLessThan(L-1)));

    }
}
```

Please help me out. Even if you can just hint me the test case for which wrong answer is coming, that will also be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in printing the answers.

In this code:

```
for(scanf("%d",&test_cases);test_cases>=0;test_cases--)
```

suppose test_cases = 1.

The loop will execute, then test_cases becomes 0, then the loop will execute again.

So you print the last answer twice.

Try:

```
for(scanf("%d",&test_cases);test_cases>0;test_cases--)
```

Comment: Ohh god, such silly mistake make me feel like killing myself. I am so sorry for asking this query and thanks a lot for not using 'stupid' word for me and giving me the answer.

Comment: No problem, you had obviously tried hard by testing against a brute force method and it was interesting for me to understand your method.  It is funny how that for loop looks perfectly correct - I only spotted the error after writing my own brute force program to compare with...